# awk + how to export value in awk

Tags: awk, variable

I use the following awk line in order to capture the remote machine that using the port 2181

```
netstat -nape | awk '{if ($4 == "43.64.56.36:2181") print $4, $5 ,$6 ,$9;}'
43.64.56.36:2181 43.64.56.60:40151 ESTABLISHED 9027/java
```

but when I use parameter - a that represented the ip address value in the awk
seems that a parameter not get the real ip address

```
 netstat -nape | awk -v a="43.64.56.36"  '{if ($4 == a:2181) print $4, $5 ,$6 ,$9;}'
```

no output

when I am wrong here ?

Comment: Are you sure it's the correct command? `$4 == a:2181` will be syntax error. You want to use `$4 == a":2181"`

Comment: what I mean is that we want a contain the ip = 43.64.56.36

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command should have given you a syntax error.

With GNU `awk`:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: {if ($4 == a:2181) print $4, $5 ,$6 ,$9;}
awk: cmd. line:1:             ^ syntax error
```

With BSD `awk`:

```
awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
        {if ($4 == >>>  a: <<<
awk: illegal statement at source line 1
```

With `mawk`:

```
mawk: line 1: syntax error at or near :
```

All of these are pointing to the syntax error at `a:2181`.

You are correctly setting the `awk` variable `a` to a string containing your IP number, but if you want to concatenate its value with `:2181` to form a new string you would have to use `:2181` as a string:  `a ":2181"`

You should also consider using the idiomatic way of matching against the input and performing an action rather than using explicit `if` statements:

```
awk -a="42.54.56.36" '$4 == a ":2181" { print $4, $5, $6, $9 }'
```

Note that there is no need to end a statement with a `;` in `awk` if there is no further statements on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

we solved it by the following syntax

```
netstat -nape | awk -v a="43.64.56.36"  '{if ($4 == a":2181") print $4, $5 ,$6 ,$9;}'
```